# Create Report Template with JRDataSource using Spring Custom Data Source

Tags: java, spring, report

I have follow the tutorial from http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jasper-integration.html to create a jasper report. Now, I need to create a template with Spring JRData Source.

What is the Factory class for Spring custom JRData Source ?

What is the static method to retrieve JRData Source ?

How to do it ?

Comment: Please help because I really no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case JRData Source is just a wrapper of a DAO class that is designed later in this tutorial (see SalesDAO). This class returns a list of sales objects (see Sales class for the full definition) which are constitute the Spring JRData Source.

You do not have to create any factory class / static method to access this data.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JRBeanCollectionDataSource, is really easy to use, just create a new instance with a List of objects, the objects of your report.

```
List<Object> reportItems = getReportItems();
JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportItems);
```

Please see this [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/jasperreports/jasperreports/3.5.3/jasperreports-3.5.3-sources.jar!/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java?format=ok), is a implementation of a JRDataSource, is a really simple interface. The main method is getFieldValue, this method receive a [JRField](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.7.1/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRField.java), (this is another simple class that have the field name) and return a Object, the toString() is the string printed in the report.

Sorry for my bad english

Cheers